# Показатель ANR в Play Market'e

Tags: android, google-play

Что отображает показатель ANR в Play Market ?

Когда приложение падает с надписью "Приложение было остановлено" и пользователь нажал на кнопку отправить отчет или когда ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ANR - Application Not Responded - Приложение не отвечает. Зависло, в общем. Вроде как более 5 секунд выполняло некую задачу в основном потоке (UI) приложения.

И да, чтобы это в консоли появилось юзер должен нажать на "отправить отчёт", автоматически такие ошибки не отправляются. Для этого нужны спец. библиотеки.

Comment: Спасибо. Думал, что гугль может сам как-то собирать эти отчеты, не обязательно юзверю нажимать на "отправить отчет"..